# html+javascript: How to disable null option in dropdownlist on some condtition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html page with a dozen dropdownlinst

One of them is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PrimaryNetworkInt, new SelectList(ViewBag.AvailableNetworks, "ID", "Name"), "Offline")
```

Second one store some other value, and when I change it to "AAA" I must disable in the fist one ability to choose NULL-oprtion (i.e. "Offline") (and return it back if was selected something else)

Select logic works fine:

```
$('#SecondDDList').change(function () { SecondDDListChanged(); });

var SecondDDListChanged() = function(){
    //...
    if ($('#SecondDDList').val()==-1){ //-1 i.e == "AAA" in my example
        //Here i need logic to disable NULL selection
    } else {
        //Here i need enable NULL option
    }
}
```

What is better way to do it? May be something like:

```
$("#PrimaryNetworkInt option[value=null]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods **.show()** and **.hide()** for be shure the user can (or can not) select the value

```
$("#PrimaryNetworkInt").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()==-1){ //-1 i.e == "AAA" in my example
        $("#PrimaryNetworkInt option[value='null']").hide();
    } else {
        $("#PrimaryNetworkInt option[value='null']").show();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#SecondDDList').find("option").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == -1 || jQuery(this).val() == "null" ) {
            jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable particular option just set its `disabled` attribute.

```
var SecondDDListChanged() = function(){
    //...
    if ($('#SecondDDList').val()==-1){ //-1 i.e == "AAA" in my example
        $("#optionId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#optionId").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```